# Is this possible to limit the application for full-size iPad only, not the iPad mini?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any params that can limit the application only show on the full-size iPad, instead of iPad mini? Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? An iPad Mini is essentially an smaller iPad 2 (same screen resolution, even) so I don't see why you would want to add such limitations.

Comment: I would like to only allow application run on the full-size iPad, because the iPad mini is too small for some information display in the 7.9" screen.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you would need to do this, as Leonnears has said, the resolution is the same as iPad 2 so you wont need to adjust anything as you did for iPad 3. iPad Mini will run all iPad 2 apps without modification.

There isn't any features you can test for in build settings which would differentiate the iPad mini from iPad 2 or 3 as it will have a camera and be running the latest OS. It may be worth looking at UIDevice class, the following may be of interest to restrict certain features if your app is running on iPad mini.

I haven't looked at the string the model property returns but I would assume it includes the model version. You would need to wait till the iPad mini is released to get its proper model name. "iPad 4,1" is an assumption, it could be "iPad Mini 1,0" or something completely different.

```
if(![[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad 4,1"])
{
     // Run code for all iPad's expect iPad Mini
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the model number, but if you do this it will probably be rejected at the apple store, since apple says all the apps for iPad will work on the ipad Mini.

Oh and if your app works for iPad 2, then you dont have to do anything for it to work on the ipad mini.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that because iPad mini screen has a same resolution as iPad 2. GUI is rendered based on screen resolution, not screen size.